теми же... что... syntax
This is from the book РОССІЯ И ЕВРЕИ 1924:

Средній обыватель-еврей живётъ въ данномъ случаѣ тѣми же чувствами и
представленіями, что русскій человѣкъ нисшихъ слоёвъ населенія:
прачка, дворникъ, которымъ тоже эта власть близка.

Can someone explain the syntax to me? теми же чувствами, что русский человек. Why not: теми же чувствами, что есть у русского человека? Or: теми же чувствами, которыми живёт русский человек? Is it the case that the syntax in such sentences is somehow abbreviated, or that что replaces a more complex relative clause?

Yes, this is sloppily written, and means: "еврей живёт теми же чувствами, которыми живёт русский человек".  The repeated "живёт" is omitted. It would be better to write, at least,"что и русский человек".

Not sloppy, just a bit archaic.

The construct тот же …, что и … (or такой же, там же, тогда же etc.) means "to be (to do, to have etc.) the same thing that the other one is (has, does)". It allows avoiding the repetition of the verb, especially if the government of the verb is complex or different for different parts of the comparison.


Николай Трофимович шил костюмы у того же портного, что и Кеннеди. [И. Э. Кио. Иллюзии без иллюзий (1995-1999)]

Nikolay Trofimovich ordered his suits from the same tailor that Kennedy did.






Проблемы у нас те же самые, что и в любой другой богословской школе России. [Иоанн Мейендорф. Православное свидетельство в современном мире (1992)]

We have the same problems that any other theology school in Russia has.






На утро (sic) шпон легко отслаивается, но при этом возможны те же последствия, что и в предыдущем способе. [Татьяна Матвеева. Реставрация столярно-мебельных изделий (1988)]

The next morning the veneer comes off easily, but the possible consequences of this are the same as those of the previous technique.




The и in your text is omitted, which is a minor stylistic flaw.
